# Icecast call auth url when any source is mounted or unmounted?

Tags: notifications, audio-streaming, icecast

I would like to be notified when any source is mounted or unmounted.

I can see [on the documentation](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html) that it could issue POST to an URL once a connection happens, so i could do the "authentication" and use that URL as my "hook".

The problem is, this configuration is mount point specific settings, which i would like to avoid, since all my mount points have the same configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.5 we will introduce events, which are more suited for what you need.

In the meantime you can use default mounts, but take care, as all backend files will be catched by the default mount, even `/stats.xsl` for example. So you might want to setup your default mount with a wildcard like `/*.ogg` or so. If your mountpoints don't all share a file extension, there is no real solution at the moment.